# HERE Maps URL not being decoded

Tags: here-maps-rest, heremaps

I'm trying to make a query to Here Maps API with JavaScript to calculate a route with waypoints, where the waypoints are of type "passThrough", the actual produced URL is (I just removed the API key):

[https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.21.3&apikey={API_KEY_HERE}&routingMode=fast&transportMode=truck&origin=25.900672%2C-80.253709&destination=40.213615%2C-97.188347&unit=imperial&truck=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&return=polyline%2CtravelSummary&via=40.052839%2C-87.410475!passThrough%3Dtrue](https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.21.3&apikey=%7BAPI_KEY_HERE%7D&routingMode=fast&transportMode=truck&origin=25.900672%2C-80.253709&destination=40.213615%2C-97.188347&unit=imperial&truck=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&return=polyline%2CtravelSummary&via=40.052839%2C-87.410475!passThrough%3Dtrue)

This query returns an error response, even when I'm following the documentation. Here is the problem I found,
If I paste this URL in the browser and remove "%3D" after "passThrough" from the URL, and explicitly change it to "=", the API then returns the expected response. Have to clarify that the URL from above works with curl -X GET. So I really think that the Here Maps API is not decoding the URL, even when they say that special characters have to be encoded.

Any clue on this?
Am I wrong?

Comment: I am having the same issue with "!stopOver=" and just sent an email to my support contact. have you found a solution?

Comment: No answer from HereMaps. My manager told me to stop the project until June, so no solution yet